# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on line 26

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting this error on my site after I tried to convert to mysqli on line 26 (*$rs = mysqli_query($link,MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());*)

My code is like this

//Get configuration control record from database

```
$MySQLi = "SELECT configValLong 
              FROM   storeadmin 
              WHERE  configVar = 'controlRec' 
              AND    adminType = 'C' ";
    $rs = mysqli_query($link,MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    $totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    if ($totalRows!=0){
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
        $configArr = trim($rows["configValLong"]);
        if (strlen($configArr) > 0 ){
            $configArr = explode("*|*",$configArr);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using `$rs = mysqli_query($link,$MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());` inside a function? Plus you need to change `MySQLi` to `$MySQLi` like Edward mentioned in his answer.

Comment: What is your `$link` code?

Comment: yes, I'm using $rs = mysqli_query($link,$MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());  inside a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined, `$link=mysqli_connect()` outside the function, you need to pass it as a parameter to the function or declare it `global` inside the function.

**1. Passing as parameter**

```
yourFunction($link); //function call, passing the variable to the function

function yourFunction($link) //you can use any name for parameter
{ //now it can be accessed here
}
```

**2. Declaring as Global inside the function**

```
function yourFunction()
    { 
    global $link;
//now it can be accessed here
    }
```

By using the keyword `global`, you are specifying that you want to use the `$link` which you have defined in `global scope`.

> You may have to do the same with `$MySQLi` and other variables if you
>   have defined them outside the function.

Comment: It worked after passing the parameter to the function

Comment: Great. Happy Coding :D
Also, to learn more about variable scope in php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: That's great. Thank you

Comment: If this answer helped you, please indicate so by clicking the `check/tick` mark on the left. And you are welcome :D

Comment: Ideally, you are supposed to start a new question but I think I will try to explain it here instead. You are getting a `deprecated warning` because all these functions with `mysql` extension like `mysql_connect()`, `mysql_pconnect()` are not supported anymore. They have been officially discontinued. You should use `mysqli_` or  `PDO_MySQL` instead. For more details on deprecated warning, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: noted. I'm unable to create a new question at this time. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

On this line: `$rs = mysqli_query($link,MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());`, your variable `MySQLi` needs the variable sign `$`.

So change that to this:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($link,$MySQLi) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

Comment: What you pointed out is important but I don't think that's the issue here though. This seems to be an issue with the scope of variable `$link`. OP is probably trying to use `$link` inside a function. `Warning is about parameter 1 and not 2`.

Comment: The error is still coming up after I changed line 26 as suggested by Edward

Comment: $link=mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword) or die(mysqli_connect_error());